# SSH clients (putty, GCP web) often displays remnants of previous command

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, centos, putty

I saw it in different SSH clients but can at least guarantee Putty and GCP web-console (SSH in a web browser) have this.

When you scroll your history and then run a previous command - sometime (more often it is long text) - you get bits of previous command stuck on the left.

It still works but display does not reflect the reality anymore. The text of the command can be figured out but cursor now behaves differently and is often not possible to properly edit the command if it fills 2-3 lines of text - cursor sticks in the middle.

This happens routinely to me with remote or local systems doesnt matter. So it is not network latency. The only constant - it is always CentOS 8/9 on the remote side and Windows on the local side.

Any ideas how to make it go away?

*Basic illustration*

```
$> some-commansome-command with params here
```

*EDIT: in hindsight the prompt variable is important and the broken one is*

`\\e[0;32m[\\u \\D{%T} \\w]\\$ \\e[m`

Comment: Did you recently customize your shell prompt? (That's a [very common problem](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/nonprintingchars.html).)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1686 I went to right path and finally figured out how to "fix" it. Apparently (and not surprisingly) 99% of blogs are just copy paste collecting money from ads.

What really needs to be said:

1. the issue is with the customized `PS1` setting
2. it can be fixed by replacing

`e[colour-codes` with `e[colour-codes]` **and** escaping each `e[]`

ie

`"\\e[0;32m[\\u \\D{%T} \\w]\\$ \\e[m "` should be `"\[\e[32m\][\\u \\D{%T} \\w]\\$\[\e[0m\] "`

Comment: No, no, no. These "`e[colour-codes`" by itself start with `\e[` (well, in fact they start with an escape character, but your shell interprets `\e` in PS1 accordingly) and this part must remain. You need to embrace non-printing characters with `\[` and `\]`. In effect `\[\e[` substring will appear.

Comment: that what i said `\e\[`

Comment: `\e\[` and `\[\e[` are obviously different.

Comment: you right i shouldve printed my actual PS1 rather..

Comment: Also note `\\ ` in double-quotes is interpreted by the shell like `\ ` in single-quotes, but `\ ` in double-quotes may be interpreted as sole `\ `. In general your snippets seem to be designed for double-quoting, but this is not obvious. The whole thing is getting messy. If you want to maintain the answer, my advice is to post `PS1="..."` or `PS1='...'` lines. If you wanted to generate a given PS1 in these two ways, the string in double-quotes should be different than the string in single-quotes. My point is: posting just one of the strings without information how to quote is hardly helpful.